# Replace a column with some [0,0,1,1] , [316.0,318.0] etc in it with ['0', '0', '1','1'] , ['316.0','318.0'] in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe (`df3`) with 266 rows which looks like below. The label columns list items are of type int.

| Id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 4cfab | [0,0,1,1] |
| 924cf | [0,0,1,1] |
| 916b8 | [316.0,318.0] |
| 0f549 | [0,0,1,1] |
| db696 | [345.0,39.0,9] |

I want the result like below:

| Id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 4cfab | ['0', '0', '1','1'] |
| 924cf | ['0', '0', '1','1'] |
| 916b8 | ['316.0','318.0'] |
| 0f549 | ['0', '0', '1','1'] |
| db696 | ['45.0','39.0','9'] |

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
df3['label'] = [str(i) for x in df3['label'] for i in x]
```

Comment: What is the type of label, list or string?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo type of label is object

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas.Series.map` method to broadcast a function over each element of the series.  In this case, each element is a list.  So for each list, we want to `map` the function `str` over each element of the list.

```
df3['label'] = df3.label.map(lambda x: list(map(str, x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as a list comprehension within a `map()`:

```
df3['label'] = df3['label'].map(lambda x: [str(y) for y in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `apply()` to add the quotation marks. The for loop in the lambda function loops through all the values within the lists in the `df3['label']` column.

```
df3['label'] = df3['label'].apply(lambda x: ["'" + str(i) + "'" for i in range(len(x))])
```